# what logic to use in the validateHeader() to capture if LOCK_FIELD is missing?

Tags: java, excel

```
public class SheetHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SheetHandler.class);

    private final SharedStringsTable sst;
    private String lastContents;
    private boolean nextIsString;
    private boolean inlineStr;
    private String cellRowCol;
    private final LruCache<Integer, String> stringTableCache;
    private CommonUtils utils = new CommonUtils();

    private FloorCeilingLocalBean bean;
    private List<FloorCeilingLocalBean> beanList;
    private int rowCount = 0;
    private int columnCount = 0;
    private static final int HEADER_ROW = 0;
    private static final int COLUMNS_MAXIMUM = 14; // restore file

    private static final String ROW = "row";
    private static final String CELL = "c";
    private static final String CELL_ROW_COL = "r"; // A cells row/column position
    private static final String CELL_VALUE = "v";
    private static final String CELL_INLINE = "t";
    private static final String CELL_TYPE = "t";
    private static final String CELL_TYPE_STRING = "s";

    private static final int STATION_CELL = 1;
    private static final int CATEGORY_CELL = 2;
    private static final int CAR_CELL = 3;
    private static final int DAILY_FLOOR_CELL = 4;
    private static final int DAILY_CEIL_CELL = 5;
    private static final int WEEKLY_FLOOR_CELL = 6;
    private static final int WEEKLY_CEIL_CELL = 7;
    private static final int MONTHLY_FLOOR_CELL = 8;
    private static final int MONTHLY_CEIL_CELL = 9;
    private static final int WEEKEND_FLOOR_CELL = 10;
    private static final int WEEKEND_CEIL_CELL = 11;
    private static final int FROM_DATE_CELL = 12;
    private static final int TO_DATE_CELL = 13;
    private static final int LOCK_RULE = 14;
    public SheetHandler(SharedStringsTable sst) {
        this.sst = sst;
        this.stringTableCache = new LruCache<>(100000);
    }

    public SheetHandler(SharedStringsTable sst, LruCache<Integer, String> stringTableCache) {
        this.sst = sst;
        this.stringTableCache = stringTableCache;
    }

    @Override
    public void startDocument() {
        beanList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private void startNewRow() {
        columnCount = 1;

        // header row
        if (rowCount != HEADER_ROW) {
            bean = new FloorCeilingLocalBean();
        }
    }

    private void endRow() {
        LOG.debug("Row: {}, Column: {},  Bean: {}",rowCount, columnCount-1, bean != null ? bean.toStringCsv() : "");
        // blank row or invalid row if the column count does not match one of these sizes
        // also don't include the header row
        int cols = columnCount - 1;
        if ((cols == COLUMNS_MAXIMUM) && (rowCount != HEADER_ROW)) {
            beanList.add(bean);
        }
        rowCount++;
    }

    @Override
    // callback function on a start tag element
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name, Attributes attributes)
    {
        // A ROW tag equals a new Floor/Ceiling bean
        if(name.equals(ROW)) {
            startNewRow();
        } else
        // A CELL tag equals a field in the bean
        if(name.equals(CELL)) {
            cellRowCol = attributes.getValue(CELL_ROW_COL);

            // for a string cell the value is an index in the SST (Shared String Table).
            // set the nextString flag, so we know to pull actual string value from the SST.
            // If from a restore file the string value will be an in-line string
            String cellType = attributes.getValue(CELL_TYPE);
            nextIsString = cellType != null && cellType.equals(CELL_TYPE_STRING);
            inlineStr = cellType != null && cellType.equals("inlineStr");
        }

        // Clear contents cache
        lastContents = "";
    }

    @Override
    // Callback function on and end tag element
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String name) {
        // If a string cell, get the actual cell value from the SST. Cache it in the LRUCache if we need it again
        if(nextIsString) {
            Integer idx = Integer.valueOf(lastContents);
            lastContents = stringTableCache.get(idx);
            if (lastContents == null && !stringTableCache.containsKey(idx)) {
                lastContents = new XSSFRichTextString(sst.getEntryAt(idx)).toString();
                stringTableCache.put(idx, lastContents);
            }
            nextIsString = false;
        }

        // A CELL_VALUE tag is the actual value in a cell
        if((name.equals(CELL_VALUE) && (rowCount > 0)) || (inlineStr && name.equals(CELL) && (rowCount > 0))) {
            setBeanValue();
            columnCount++;
        }

        //
        if((name.equals(CELL_VALUE) && (rowCount == 0)) || (inlineStr && name.equals(CELL) && (rowCount == 0))) {
            validateHeader();
            columnCount++;
        }

        // Ending ROW tag means end of bean population, so add bean to bean list
        if(name.equals(ROW)) {
            endRow();
        }
    }

    // Based on the column set the corresponding field value in the bean.
    // For any exceptions, the field in the bean will not be populated and the validator will filter it out
    private void setBeanValue() {
        try {
            switch (columnCount) {
                case STATION_CELL: bean.setStation(StringUtils.trim(lastContents)); break;
                case CATEGORY_CELL: bean.setCategory(lastContents); break;
                case CAR_CELL: bean.setCar(lastContents); break;
                case DAILY_FLOOR_CELL: bean.setDailyFloorAmt(Float.parseFloat(lastContents)); break;
                case DAILY_CEIL_CELL: bean.setDailyCeilingAmt(Float.parseFloat(lastContents)); break;
                case WEEKLY_FLOOR_CELL: bean.setWeeklyFloorAmt(Float.parseFloat(lastContents)); break;
                case WEEKLY_CEIL_CELL: bean.setWeeklyCeilingAmt(Float.parseFloat(lastContents)); break;
                case MONTHLY_FLOOR_CELL: bean.setMonthlyFloorAmt(Float.parseFloat(lastContents)); break;
                case MONTHLY_CEIL_CELL: bean.setMonthlyCeilingAmt(Float.parseFloat(lastContents)); break;
                case WEEKEND_FLOOR_CELL: bean.setWeekendFloorAmt(Float.parseFloat(lastContents)); break;
                case WEEKEND_CEIL_CELL: bean.setWeekendCeilingAmt(Float.parseFloat(lastContents)); break;
                case FROM_DATE_CELL: bean.setFromDate( utils.getLocalDate(lastContents)); break;
                case TO_DATE_CELL: bean.setToDate( utils.getLocalDate(lastContents)); break;
                case LOCK_RULE: bean.setRuleLock(lastContents.equals("Y") ? true : false); break;
                default: LOG.warn("Unknown cell position: row={}, column={}  and value={} ", rowCount, columnCount, lastContents);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.warn("Unable to parse cell {} value={}", cellRowCol, lastContents);
        }
     }

    /**
     * Validate each header cell. An Invalid header name or additional columns invalidates the load
     * of the file. Within Excel a column that is empty is not seen by the XML. For the header row
     * we also need to verify that the header is always in the correct column/row position to account for this.
     */
    private void validateHeader() { // not reading the to_date and lock_field heading.
        int columnNdx = columnCount - 1; // zero based array
        if (columnCount <= COLUMNS_MAXIMUM) { // need to avoid out-of-bounds on header array
            int compareNameResult = StringUtils.compareIgnoreCase(HEADERS[columnNdx], StringUtils.trim(lastContents));
            int comparePosResult = StringUtils.compareIgnoreCase(HEADER_POS[columnNdx], cellRowCol);
            boolean lockFieldPresent = HEADERS[columnNdx].equalsIgnoreCase("LOCK_FIELD");
            if ((compareNameResult != 0) || (comparePosResult != 0) && !lockFieldPresent) {
                LOG.error("{} column is either missing or misplaced. Please verify file layout.", HEADERS[columnNdx]);
                throw new UnprocessableException(HEADERS[columnNdx] + " column is either missing or misplaced. Please verify file layout.");
            }
        }
    }

    public List<FloorCeilingLocalBean> getResultList() {
        return beanList;
    }

    // acct for header by subtracting 1
    public int getRowCount() {
        return rowCount-1;
    }

    public FloorCeilingLocalBean getBean() {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) {
        lastContents += new String(ch, start, length);
    }
}
```

I added `lockFieldPresent = HEADERS[columnNdx].equalsIgnoreCase("LOCK_FIELD")` to capture if LOCK_FIELD is missing, but when I tested the code by removing the field from the excel file, the error.log under validateHeaders did not produce the error message.